# Cleaning up filenames from MAC using Powershell

Tags: powershell, character

I'm writing a script that iterates over files that are copied from a MAC computer to a Exfat disk and checks the name of the files for Windows forbidden characters.(Writing it in PowerShell)

And hopefully replace the forbidden characters with another character, for example a "-".

Why i am doing this is because i see it as a good way for me to practice coding and it might be used in my work when we get users with a lot of local files that we want to move to Onedrive.(Onedrive has a function to rename but it doesn't touch the forbidden characters, and i don't know Bash)

The issue is when I'm trying to find the characters within the script itself, it cant find the characters if i write them in the script.(For example if i write that it should look for ">")
Even if i escape the characters it just skips it(Or rather doesn't find it).

It just skips over the file i know has one in it, at first i though it might be due to encoding, but no matter what i use as a default encoding it wont display the filename correctly.(I assume this is due to how Windows reads filenames?)

edit: These are the forbidden characters im goint to look for `" * : < > ? / \ |`
The script itself is able to remove letters and stuff if i ask it  to.

I also tried getting the char of the byte([byte][char]"") but i get this error:
`Cannot convert value "" to type "System.Byte". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte."` Edit: the  changed by itself during the day not sure what to say.

If i just add it to the function it just returns the error:`Rename-Item : The input to the script block for parameter 'NewName' failed. Exception calling "Replace" with "2" argument(s): "String cannot be of zero length.`

The characters are displayed like this in visual studio code.
[image: Here is a image of the character]

Any ideas are welcome or if you know of any better ways of doing it?(Maybe its better if i just learn bash. )

Here is the script itself:
edit: cleaned up the script abit and some small changes.

````ps
$provided_path = Read-Host "What Directory and its subfolders do you want to check?"
# Iterates over the folders and files within.
Write-Host "Creating list of files..."
$dictionary_filenames = ""
$dictionary_filenames = Get-ChildItem -Path $provided_path -Recurse -Force -File | Select-Object FullName,BaseName,Extension

# Resetting counter
$counter_skipped = 0

# Function for character replacment
function rename_file_name($names_function,$forbidden_char){

    $old_name = $names_function.BaseName
    $new_name = $names_function | Rename-Item -LiteralPath $names_function.FullName -NewName{$_.BaseName.Replace("$forbidden_char","-") + $_.extension} -PassThru

    if($old_name -ne $new_name.BaseName){
        Write-host "$old_name changed to $new_name"
    }

}

foreach($names in $dictionary_filenames){
    
    if($names.BaseName[0] -eq "." -and $names.BaseName[1] -match "_"){
        $counter_skipped ++
        $counter ++
        continue
    }
    else{

        if($names.BaseName[0] -eq " " -or $names.BaseName[-1] -eq " "){

            $old_name = $names.BaseName
            $new_name = $names | Rename-Item -LiteralPath $names.FullName -NewName{$_.BaseName.trim() + $_.extension} -PassThru
    
            Write-Host "Trimming whitespace: $old_name"
        }
        else{
            Write-Host "Trimming not needed "$names.BaseName
        }

                Write-host "Checking forbidden characters "$names.BaseName

                rename_file_name $names ">"
                rename_file_name $names "<"
                rename_file_name $names "/"

    }
}

Write-Host "Files checked: "$dictionary_filenames.Count
Write-Host "Files Skipped: "$counter_skipped

Read-Host 'Close window by pressing "Enter"'```
````

Comment: `-match "."` will match _any_ character. You want `$names.Basename[0] -eq '.'`. For the new name, try `$_.BaseName.Trim().Replace($forbidden_char, "") + $_.Extension`.

Comment: Hi, i didn't know "." matches anything thanks for pointing that out!
Sadly it still wont find the forbidden characters in the filenames, but its trimming properly at least.

Comment: Your error message suggest that was passed to `-NewName` was the _empty string_, which seems inconsistent with your code. In principle, to replace multiple characters, use a `-replace` operation such as in the following example: `'a"b*c:d<e>f?g/h\i|jk' -replace '["*:<>?/\\|]', '-'`

Comment: Hi, not sure how i am supposed to use -replace in conjunction with the rename tag or do i need to totally scrap that idea?(Using rename)

Comment: This can be shortened.  `$counter_skipped = $counter_skipped + 1` to this `$counter_skipped++`

Comment: Do any files actually have an asterisk?  It is going to be tricky to find files which contain an asterisk, as the asterisk means 'match anything'

Comment: Hi, yes one of the files has a asterisk, it doesnt show when i open the USB i have the files on currently.(Test files with all the forbidden characters in the name)
I thought it would be enough to escape the asterisk to be able to read it, but i cant currently not find a single of the characters.

Comment: Could be a duplicate of [Unsupported Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70000649/unsupported-characters)

Answer (score 0):

 is U+F021, two bytes long or [int16]. You can put it in a utf8 *with bom* encoded script.

Comment: Intressting it changed itself that is supposed to be a / from the filename i have.
But thanks for the input.